# A question concerning the definition of odd functions

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus

Calculate $E(X^{2n+1})$ knowing that $X$ is a normal random variable with mean $0$ and variance $1$.

We define $g(x) = X^{2n+1} e^{-x^2/2}$. Since $g(x)$ is an odd function then, *"for symmetric limits"* $$\int_{- \infty}^{\infty} g(x)dx = 0$$.

For the definition of an odd function:

$1)$ $-g(x)=g(-x)$

$2)$ $\int_{- \infty}^{\infty} g(x)dx < \infty$

Is this correct?

What does it mean by *"for symmetric limits"*? the function should be symmetric around 0, isn't it? but here not!

Also, to prove that the integral converges, we compare it with the integral 
$\big|\int_{- \infty}^{\infty} e^{-x} dx \big|$ which converges absolutley but why with this function exactly? what is the intuition?

Comment: Symmetric limits here means the integration limits are symmetric about $0$, that is integrals of the form $\int_{-a}^ag(t)dt$. When $g(t)$ is an odd function of $t$, this integral is $0$.

Comment: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x}\ \mathsf dx$ does not converge. Perhaps you are instead thinking of $x\mapsto e^{-x^2}$? In that case, recall that for a normal random variable with $\mu=0$ and $\sigma^2=1$, the density is
$$
x\mapsto \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac12x^2}.
$$
Do you see the connection now?

Comment: @Math1000 here is the reference uses $e^{-x}$ not $e^{-x^2}$ https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter4/4_2_3_normal.php

Comment: There they have stated $|\int_0^\infty e^{-u}\ \mathsf du|<\infty$ which is true. Be sure to mind the limits of integration.